# Will I lose my databases after re installation of pgAdmin?

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I was facing an error in starting my pgAdmin which is

[image]

and when I deleted few unwanted file and uninstall some programs to improve system performance. Now I'm getting another error in starting my pgAdmin which is

[image]

I don't know perhaps I mistakenly deleted a necessary .dll file.
So how will I fix this problem?

Is there some way of fixing so that I will not lose my databases?

Comment: You can always back up your databases using `pg_dump` to avoid any potential issues.

Comment: "*when I deleted few unwanted file*" - I hope that didn't include `vcruntime140_1.dll`

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin merely accesses existing databases, and is not the database itself. Therefore, removing/replacing/updating pgAdmin will have no affect on the underlying database.

pgAdmin *can* delete your database, etc, but you'd have to actually execute delete commands in order to do that.

Comment: this is not exactly true. Postgres itself needs `vcruntime140.dll` as well. So if you delete that from e.g. `c:\Program Files\System32` then Postgres won't start any longer (and probably many other Programs as well...)

Comment: fair enough, but removing pgadmin or reinstalling it won't erase or even touch the data part of the database.

Comment: I reinstalled pgAdmin but still showing same error in launching.As before I'm still able to access my databases by Django admin page.When I searched for " vcruntime140_1.dll "

Comment: vcruntime is microsoft redistributable dll, it's free and available from microsoft. Simple web search will locate it.

Comment: I downloaded " vcruntime140.dll " and now I'm able to launch pgAdmin.